# php - str_replace

Tags: php, utf-8, str-replace

Estoy en PHP con mi siguiente problema. En una variable recibo el apellido del usuario pero si el apellido es por ejemplo, `Hernández` la variable guarda `Hern\u00e1ndez`.

Para que el apellido puedo posteriormente mandarlo como toca en un json, estoy intentando hacer lo que leí en una respuesta de Stackoverflow ingles:

```
$lastname_consumer = $ordendetalle['customer_lastname']; //recibo el apellido
$str_lastname = str_replace('\u','u',$lastname_consumer);
$lastname = preg_replace('/u([\da-fA-F]{4})/', '&#x\1;', $str_lastname);

$customer = array ( 'customer' => array ( 'id' => $ordendetalle['customerId'], 
                                          'lastname' => $lastname, //Hern\u00e1ndez 
                                        )                        
                  );

$customer_order = print_r(json_encode($customer), true); //Para pintarlo
```

Mi problema es que ya de primeras `$str_lastname` está guardando `Hern\u00e1ndez` en vez de `Hernu00e1ndez` al hacer el `str_replace()`, y de nada vale para posteriormente hacer el `preg_replace()` y obtener `Hernández`.

Por otro lado, he probado el código en http://phptester.net/ y me funciona perfectamente pero entiendo que es tema de que `\u00e1` sea un carácter **UTF-8**. Así que no se muy bien como avanzar en este punto.

**EDIT ACLARATORIO**:

En mi PHP recibo un objeto llamado `$ordendetalle` que **se genera en una parte del servidor donde no tengo acceso**... `$ordendetalle` es un array que contiene, en campos `string`, diferentes valores que hay que tratar y entre ellos el apellido:

```
$ordendetalle['customer_lastname'];//Hernu00e1ndez en vez de Hernández
```

Recalco que el problema está a la hora del:

```
$str_lastname = str_replace('\u','u',$lastname_consumer);
```

Que no reemplaza \u por el carácter dado.
Gracias por vuestro tiempo!

Comment: Tienes configurado todas las tecnologías en la codificación utf-8? Debería funcionar bien.

Comment: El archivo PHP que tengo tiene codificación UTF-8 pero de donde vienen los datos lo desconozco porque en este proyecto solo tengo acceso a un modulo de una web.... una gracia, vamos...

Comment: prueba si te funciona asi: $str_lastname = str_replace('\\u','u',$lastname_consumer);

Comment: Si he entendido bien, ¿no tienes control sobre la fuente que genera los datos?

Comment: Así es @A.Cedano tengo un objeto array que recibo en el archivo del cual extraigo los dados para manejarlos ($ordendetalle; se ve en el ejemplo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final he resuelto la duda por otro lado, así que procedo a explicar.

El problema finalmente no se soluciona mendiante el `str_replace`, ya que al hacer un `var_dump($ordendetalle)` obtenemos.

```
["customer_id"]=> string(3) "979"
["customer_email"]=> string(23) "email@test.es"
["customer_firstname"]=> string(7) "UserTest"
["customer_lastname"]=> string(10) "Hernández"
```

Es decir, el apellido esta guardado bien dentro del objeto `$ordendetalle`. El problema reside en el la forma en que `json` codifica los caracteres "*especiales*".
`json_encode` preferiblemente codifica caracteres no ASCII usando `\u....` secuencias de escape.

Para evitar que `json_encode` codifique usando estas secuencias se utiliza `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` y no necesitaría nada del `str_replace` ni el `preg_replace`, porque al recibir `Hern\u00e1ndez` y hacer `json_encode` con `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` evitamos el uso de la secuencia `\u00e1` y codifica `á` con de tal forma que quería así:

```
//$lastname_consumer = $ordendetalle['customer_lastname']; //recibo el apellido
//$str_lastname = str_replace('\u','u',$lastname_consumer);
//$lastname = preg_replace('/u([\da-fA-F]{4})/', '&#x\1;', $str_lastname);

$customer = array ( 'customer' => array ( 'id' => $ordendetalle['customerId'], 
                                          'lastname' => $ordendetalle['lastname'], //Hern\u00e1ndez 
                                       )                        
                  );

$customer_order = print_r(json_encode($customer,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE), true);
```

Y pintaría:

```
        "id": "979",
        "lastname": "Hernández"
```

Una explicación mas teórica de `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` y donde al final he acabado resolviendo la duda lo tenéis [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745662/reference-why-are-my-special-unicode-characters-encoded-weird-using-json-enco)

Answer (score 2):

Supongamos que el endpoint adonde preguntas el nombre obtiene un objeto en la respuesta y te lo entrega json_encoded, que es lo que debiera hacer el API si te va a entregar un json y no un simple string:

```
<?php
$input = ['nombre'=>'joaquín', 'apellido'=>'hernández'];
$utf8_encoded = json_encode($input);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($utf8_encoded);
echo '</pre>';
```

Lo que obtienes, i.e. lo que entrega el API tiene la forma:

```
{"nombre":"joaqu\u00edn","apellido":"hern\u00e1ndez"}
```

Tú debieras poder hacer:

```
$json_decoded=json_decode($utf8_encoded,true);
echo 'str_lastname: '.$json_decoded['apellido'].PHP_EOL;
```

Y obtener limpiamente

```
Hernández
```

**Pero si quieres seguir el camino del reemplazo:**

```
$lastname_consumer = 'Hern\u00e1ndes';

$replaced =  str_replace("\u",'&',$lastname_consumer);
echo 'replaced: '.$replaced.PHP_EOL; // replaced: Hern&00e1ndes


$preg_replaced = preg_replace('/&([\da-fA-F]{4})/', '&#x\1;',$replaced); 
echo 'preg_replaced: '.$preg_replaced.PHP_EOL; // preg_replaced: Hernándes

// pero lo que en realidad contiene $preg_replaces es...    
$entities = htmlentities($preg_replaced);
echo 'entities: '.$entities.PHP_EOL; // entities: Hern&#x00e1;ndes
```

Como ves, `$preg_replaced` en realidad contiene:

```
Hern&#x00e1;ndes
```

Que se imprime en pantalla como `Hernández` porque, mal que mal, PHP es un procesador de Hipertexto y por defecto imprimirá la entidad HTML `&#x00e1;` como `é`.

Lo mismo podría conseguirse haciendo:

```
$lastname_consumer = 'Hern\u00e1ndes';
$preg_replace = preg_replace('/\\\\u([\da-fA-F]{4})/', '&#x\1;', $lastname_consumer);
```

Dependiendo de algunas opciones de configuración y extensiones, tu reemplazo mediante expresiones regulares podría fallar o no entregar los resultados esperados. **Por eso lo primero que te sugerí, usando simplemente json_decode, me parece la solución más sana**:

```
echo json_decode('"Hern\u00e1ndez"') // imprime Hernández
```

Comment: El archivo PHP que puedo controlar recibe un objeto array donde todos los campos string. `$ordendetalle` contiene los campos de diferentes datos a utilizar.
He probado y problema sigue siendo que str_replace no sustituye `\u` por el carácter que sea

Comment: no tienes otro servidor donde probarlo? algún hosting compartido? Yo lo probé en mi local y en [Tehplayground](https://www.tehplayground.com/J9YiwUddyvrWjQRQ). Qué versión de PHP usas? ¿Probaste hacer json_decode del string que contiene el caracter? tienes que hacer literalmente `json_decode('"Hern\u00e1ndes"')`. Comilla doble dentro de comillas simples